# 8192 limit, when debugging a Haxe project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, haxe

Setup: Win10, IntelliJ IDEA 15, Haxe 3.2.1, OpenFL 3.6.1

The project is a simple "hello world", compiled with OpenFL, targeted to Flash.

**The problem**:

When running it in the debug mode from the IDE, the classic "Failed to connect" message is shown, which goes as follows:

> "D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA
>   15.0.6\jre\jre\bin\java.exe" "-Dapplication.home=D:\Program Files_sdk\flex_sdk_4.6" -Xmx384m -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
>   -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=en -Xmx512m -classpath "D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA
>   15.0.6\plugins\flex\lib\idea-fdb-4.5.0.20967-fix.jar;D:/Program Files/_sdk/flex_sdk_4.6/lib/fdb.jar" flex.tools.debugger.cli.DebugCLI
>
> Adobe fdb (Flash Player Debugger) [build 23201]
>
> Copyright (c) 2004-2007 Adobe, Inc. All rights reserved.
>
> Waiting for Player to connect
>
> Failed to connect; session timed out.
>
> Ensure that:
>
> 1. you compiled your Flash movie with debugging on, and
> 2. you are running the Debugger version of the Flash Player.

As I've investigated, this message is shown only when the Make command output is too long. In my case it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEA1e.png).
Note the long asset names, they are made like that to reproduce the problem. If I make the output shorter, the debug Flash player connects as expected. Also, the project runs normally, when started in the non-debug mode, even if the output is long. Perhaps, it is somehow related to the problem, described here: https://mcuoneclipse.com/2015/03/29/solving-the-8192-character-command-line-limit-on-windows/

Any suggestions how can I resolve that? Maybe it is possible to turn off the `-verbose` flag somehow? I wasn't able to find where can I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else struggles with this problem, I can recommend rebuilding the plugin (see instructions here: https://github.com/TiVo/intellij-haxe/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) and remove the

```
commandLine.addParameter("-verbose");
```

line from the

```
com.intellij.plugins.haxe.runner.OpenFLRunningState
```

class.